# How to find a json dictionary key name and values using date condition in python

Tags: python, json, pandas

Given a Github URL e.g. `https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos`, I need to find the owner login, owner key, license key, license name for all the repositories which were created_at or after `2013-06-04`, and update the created_at by a month.

I have this code but I need help from here:

```
import pandas as pd 
import json
url = "https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos"
df = pd.read_json(url)
print(df)
```

Comment: Well, when you `print(df)`, does it appear that the DataFrame contains the data you need? Does it successfully create the DataFrame? Do you know how to do any kind of manipulation of DataFrames? What actually is your *question*?

Comment: What does "update" mean? Are you only trying to change the data in your DataFrame? Do you want to change the Github repository? Something else? If you want to change the repository, are you sure Github actually lets you do that? After all, the actual file was created when it was created, and changes to the files (or new files) are supposed to come from using Git.

Comment: I don't want to change Github repository, just need to owner login, owner key, license key, license name which were created_at or after 2013-06-04 and update the created_at by a month @KarlKnechtel